# Send chart image in automated email

Tags: 2010, email, chart-web-part, chart

The scenario is this:

A monthly progress report email is sent to managers which contains, at present, links to a page with sharepoint chart web parts on it. Because people are lazy and don't like clicking on links, this information is not reaching its audience. Would it be possible to embed in the email an image or view of the charts rather than using hyperlinks, preferably without using code?

(Since this question was asked we now have the option to code and can use excel pivotcharts in conjunction with an excel viewer web part instead of chart web parts if this helps)

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am in same issue now. Would you please help?